# Convert tab separated to a human readable aligned column headers

Tags: spreadsheet, csv

Let's say I have a spreadsheet with the following example data:

[image: example data table]

I need to display this in plain text but still human readable.

When saved in a tab separated format (tsv) it will output something like this (I've included the tab and line break symbols for clarity).

[image: tsv without symbols]

[image: data as tsv with symbols]

*Is there an automated way to make it more human readable i.e. aligning the data to the heading values* e.g.

[image: plain text data more readable]

A windows or web based solution would be best (as I need it for work), but a linux or mac based solutions would be welcome to.

Comment: Could someone add the tsv tag please, as I don't have enough reputation on superuser.

Comment: Do you use Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: Yes @JacobJanTuinstra

Comment: Why don't you tag the post accordingly?

Comment: I use Google Spreadsheets in general, however this question is relevant to the file type itself as it's to display as plain text. Tagging with Google spreadsheets would be misleading as it would state that I was looking for explicitly a google spreadsheets solution. However I am open to using Google spreadsheets etc if it's to produce the desired output. Thanks for your feedback Jacob.

Answer (score 1):

The VSCode plugin Auto Align does a great job of this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.align-mode

[image]

I would also recommend when working with CSV/TSV:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mechatroner.rainbow-csv

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The good news: /rdb, a product from Revolutionary Software, is exactly what you need.  It is  suite of add-on shell commands to work tab-separated database files - sort, shuffle, re-arrange, combine, justify, whatever.  Used it in Coherent, Xenix, Unix, and RedHat Linux.  Marvelous!

The bad news: that was around 1998.  Revolutionary Software, as a company, likely been his-to-ry for a decade.  If you can find a copy, please tell me where.

Comment: Okay, so what's your point exactly? Just to recommend old software with no confirmation that it sufficed for the need of the OP or what? Respectfully~